# wpf binding several checkboxes' ischecked to static list

Tags: arrays, wpf, checkbox, binding, static

This is a re-cap of the second part of a question I posted, and understanding that putting two questions in one entry is not playing nice, here goes:

I am programmatically creating several checkboxes and adding them to a StackPanel named `myStackPanel`, using a foreach loop. I can change that to any other type of construction (an array, for example):

```
foreach (something)
{
    CheckBox newCheckBox = new CheckBox();
    myStackPanel.Children.Add(newcheckBox);
}
```

In addition, there's a non-static class `myClass` with a static property `myStaticList`:

```
public class myClass
{
    public static ObservableCollection<bool> myStaticList { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to bind the isChecked of the dynamically-created checkboxes to `myStaticList`. I have no idea how to do this.

Help please! TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to **bind** the `IsChecked` property, then this is how you can do it in code behind:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < myClass.myStaticList.Count; i++)
        {
            CheckBox newCheckBox = new CheckBox();

            Binding binding = new Binding();
            binding.Path = new PropertyPath(string.Format("[{0}]", i));
            binding.Source = myClass.myStaticList;
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(newCheckBox, CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, binding);

            myStackPanel.Children.Add(newCheckBox);
        }
```

**Update:**

Another solution is to handle this in XAML:

```
    <ItemsControl x:Name="myStackPanel" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:myClass.myStaticList}}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=., Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

In this solution, instead of creating dynamic `CheckBoxes`, you can pre-define your `ItemTemplate` as a `CheckBox` and add `bool` data dynamically like this:

```
foreach(something)
{
    myClass.myStaticList.Add(true or false);
}
```

Note that `myStaticList` has to be instantiated in the static constructor of `myClass`:

```
public class myClass
{
    public static ObservableCollection<bool> myStaticList { get; set; }

    static myClass()
    {
        myStaticList = new ObservableCollection<bool>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... Doesn't seem to work. In addition, this requires to initialize myStaticList in the correct size, but in my application this can change dynamically.

Comment: Is there a way to do the binding entirely programmatically, as you suggested above, without a loop? I mean - set that an array of checkboxes is linked to an ObservableCollection as a whole? 
Thanks, @Bahman_Aries

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't quite understand what you mean could you please elaborate?

Comment: Hi @Bahman_Aries - Please see my new and specific question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31784400/wpf-c-entirely-programmatically-binding-an-array-of-objects-to-a-static-observa