# WPF/C# entirely programmatically binding an array of objects to a static ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, checkbox, binding

Please assume this entire question deals in code, without any XAML.

I have a static `ObservableCollection` named `myStaticList`. It's a part of a non-static class named `myClass`.

```
public class myClass
{
    public static ObservableCollection<CheckBoxStructure> myStaticList { get; set; }

    static myClass()
    {
        myStaticList = new ObservableCollection<CheckBoxStructure>();
    }
}
```

And the definition of `CheckBoxStructure`:

```
public class CheckBoxStructure
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

In addition, there's an array of checkboxes called `checkBoxArray[]`, holding 3 elements. each checkbox has as content a textbox.

What I want to do is programmatically bind (two-way) these two, in such a manner that the `IsChecked` property of the checkboxes in the `checkBoxArray[]` array will bind to the `IsSelected` property of the `myStaticList`'s `CheckBoxStructure`, and similarly so between the text of the textboxes inthe checkboxes' content and the `Description` property of the `myStaticList`'s `CheckBoxStructure`.

In addition, I would like to avoid using loops, since it is preferable that this two lists will update each other if they change in size.

How is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: @Bahman_Aries: Thanks for the edit. Just a typing error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using XAML, an easy way would be to the declare an `ItemsControl` and a `DataTemplate` for it so that you can have a `UserControl` (`CheckBox` and `TextBox` inside) with its `DataContext` being a `CheckBoxStructure`. This way the bindings work between `CheckBox.IsChecked` and `IsSelected` property and between `TextBox.Text` and `Description` property.
If you need to this only in code then you would have to create same behavior (`ItemsControl` with a `DataTemplate`). You have at least 2 options

**1.**

```
DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate();
FrameworkElementFactory factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
template.VisualTree = factory;
FrameworkElementFactory childFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
childFactory.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsChecked, new Binding("IsSelected"));
factory.AppendChild(childFactory);
childFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
childFactory.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, new Binding("Description"));
factory.AppendChild(childFactory);
```

**2.**

```
MemoryStream sr = null;
ParserContext pc = null;
string xaml = string.Empty;
xaml = "<DataTemplate><StackPanel><TextBlock Text="{Binding Description"/><CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected"/></StackPanel></DataTemplate>";
sr = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xaml));
pc = new ParserContext();
pc.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
pc.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
DataTemplate datatemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(sr, pc);
this.Resources.Add("dt", datatemplate);
```

Later edit, after discussion from comments; this example works only one way of binding but is easily to make it two ways. Please note that this is only a trivial example of a concept and is not complete: you need to modify the list classes to suit how you wish for objects to be paired, you may need to add more guards for corner cases, you may need to make it thread safe and so on...

First the basic binding objects:

```
class Binder
{
    public Binder()
    {
        _bindings = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    }

    private INotifyPropertyChanged _dataContext;

    public INotifyPropertyChanged DataContext
    {
        get { return _dataContext; }
        set
        {
            if (_dataContext != null)
            {
                _dataContext.PropertyChanged -= _dataContext_PropertyChanged;
            }

            _dataContext = value;

            _dataContext.PropertyChanged += _dataContext_PropertyChanged;
        }
    }

    void _dataContext_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_bindings.ContainsKey(e.PropertyName))
        {
            var bindableType = _dataContext.GetType();
            var bindableProp = bindableType.GetProperty(e.PropertyName);
            if (bindableProp == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var binderType = this.GetType();
            foreach (var binderPropName in _bindings[e.PropertyName])
            {
                var binderProp = binderType.GetProperty(binderPropName);
                if (binderProp == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var value = bindableProp.GetValue(_dataContext);
                binderProp.SetValue(this, value);
            }
        }
    }

    Dictionary<string, List<string>> _bindings;

    public void AddBinding(string binderPropertyName, string bindablePropertyName)
    {
        if (!_bindings.ContainsKey(bindablePropertyName))
        {
            _bindings.Add(bindablePropertyName, new List<string>());
        }
        _bindings[bindablePropertyName].Add(bindablePropertyName);
    }
}

class Bindable : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Then the holding lists for them:

```
class BindableList<T> : List<T> where T : Bindable
{
    public event Action<T> ItemAdded;

    public new void Add(T item)
    {
        base.Add(item);
        NotifyItemAdded(item);
    }

    private void NotifyItemAdded(T item)
    {
        if (ItemAdded != null)
        {
            ItemAdded(item);
        }
    }
}

class BinderList<T> : List<T> where T : Binder
{
    public BinderList()
    {
        _bindingRules = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    private BindableList<Bindable> _dataContextList;
    public BindableList<Bindable> DataContextList
    {
        get { return _dataContextList; }
        set
        {
            if (_dataContextList != null)
            {
                _dataContextList.ItemAdded -= _dataContextList_ItemAdded;
            }
            _dataContextList = value;

            _dataContextList.ItemAdded += _dataContextList_ItemAdded;
        }
    }

    void _dataContextList_ItemAdded(Bindable obj)
    {
        foreach (var pair in _bindingRules)
        {
            this[Count-1].AddBinding(pair.Key, pair.Value);
            this[Count - 1].DataContext = obj;
        }
    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> _bindingRules;
    public void AddBindingRule(string binderPropertyName, string bindablePropertyName)
    {
        _bindingRules.Add(binderPropertyName, bindablePropertyName);
    }
}
```

Now the actual classes with properties:

```
class BinderElement : Binder
{
    private string _description;

    public string Description
    {
        get { return _description; }
        set { _description = value; }
    }
}

class BindableElement : Bindable
{
    private string _description;
    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return _description;
        }
        set
        {
            _description = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Description");
        }
    }
}
```

And an example to use them:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bindableList = new BindableList<Bindable>();

        var binderList = new BinderList<BinderElement>()
        {
            new BinderElement(),
            new BinderElement()
        };

        binderList.DataContextList = bindableList;
        binderList.AddBindingRule("Description", "Description");

        bindableList.Add(new BindableElement());
        bindableList.Add(new BindableElement());

        ((BindableElement)bindableList[1]).Description = "This should arrive in BinderElement Description property";

        Console.WriteLine(binderList[1].Description);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try option #1. I must say it looks that either I wasn't clear enough in my question, or that there is a simpler solution to this. Let me ask you this: If the binding was supposed to be between two arrays (arrayOne with properties arrayOneProp1 and arrayOneProp2 and arrayTwo with properties arrayTwoProp1 and arrayTwoProp2) - no controls: Would it be simpler to bind ?

Comment: If you have no controls then you do not have to follow WPF way of working. So you must have or design another binding system. But I don't think that dealing with WPF you can make this to be simpler.

Comment: Could you please suggest a solution if no controls are involved?

Comment: Do you want a small and simple solution only with basic C# types?

Comment: Please. A simple solution with two arrays as I stated above, two-way.